# Java. Using a boolean to check if a entered digit is the right length

Tags: java

I'm doing a problem out of my Java text book for school next year, and I can't figure how to make this work right. It wants me to use a boolean to check if the entered digit is 6 digits long. I'm going to copy and paste the problem for more clarity.

> **Travel Tickets Company sells tickets for airlines, tours, and other travel-related
>
> services. Because ticket agents frequently mistype long ticket
>   numbers, Travel
>
> Tickets has asked you to write an application that indicates invalid
>   ticket number
>
> entries. The class prompts a ticket agent to enter a six-digit ticket
>   number. Ticket
>
> numbers are designed so that if you drop the last digit of the number,
>   then divide the
>
> number by 7, the remainder of the division will be identical to the
>   last dropped digit.
>
> This process is illustrated in the following example:
>
> Step 1 Enter the ticket number; for example, 123454.
>
> Step 2 Remove the last digit, leaving 12345.
>
> Step 3 Determine the remainder when the ticket number is divided by 7.
>   In this
>
> Step 4 Assign the Boolean value of the comparison between the
>   remainder and
>
> Step 5 Display the result—true or false—in a message box.
>
> case, 12345 divided by 7 leaves a remainder of 4.
>
> the digit dropped from the ticket number.
>
> Accept the ticket number from the agent and verify whether it is a
>   valid number.
>
> Test the application with the following ticket numbers:
>
> l 123454; the comparison should evaluate to true
>
> l 147103; the comparison should evaluate to true
>
> l 154123; the comparison should evaluate to false
>
> Save the program as TicketNumber.java.**

here is my code

```
//variables
int ticketNum;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//prompt for input of ticket number
System.out.println("Please enter a ticket number >> ");
ticketNum = input.nextInt();

//arithmetic for figuring out ticket number
int lastDigit = ticketNum / 10;
boolean ticketValidation = (lastDigit % 7) == ticketNum;

//output for validation
System.out.println("this ticket number is " + ticketValidation);
```

every time I run it, it comes out as false.

thank you for any help, please don't be mean, I'm new here.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the input length?

Comment: "int lastDigit = ticketNum / 10;" - that is not the last digit. That is ticketNum divided by 10.

Comment: get input length and check if it's equal to 6...

Comment: % 10 = get last digit.

Comment: @AndrewL. how do i do that?

Comment: `String.valueOf(ticketNum).length() == 6`

Answer (score 3):

`int lastDigit = ticketNum / 10;` doesn't give you the last digit, it gives you all except the last digit.
Then `(lastDigit % 7)` gives you one-tenth of the original ticketNum, mod 7. That will be an `int` between 0 and 6, inclusive.

There is no way that an `int` between 0 and 6, inclusive, will equal the original six-digit number!

That process is called "pen-checking", and you should use it.

Describe to us in words what the algorithm should be, please.

Comment: I don't know where you heard the phrase "pen-checking", but the rest of this answer is solid.

Comment: Great answer but I am with user2357112 not sure what you mean by pen-checking.

Comment: Pen-checking refers to if you have a physical piece of paper and you're trying to count some digits on it, where you would use your pen as a pointer to point at each digit as you counted.

Comment: Simulation of an algorithm: computer (computor) language: Knuth advises the reader that "the best way to learn an algorithm is to try it . . . immediately take pen and paper and work through an example"
Cited in WIkipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm#cite_note-35

The term was popular when I was taking computer programming in college, and apparently is a lost skill if everyone is professing ignorance of it. You do know what "pen" and "paper" are?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
int remainingDigits = ticketNum/10;
int lastDigit = ticketNum%10;
boolean ticketValidation = (remainingDigit % 7) == lastDigit;
```

Comment: No explanation and just an answer. This doesn't help him learn the issue.

Comment: @easiestripes thank you! i knew there was something wrong with my logic and i could not for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: It was a very simple fix, he was completely able to figure that out himself based on the variable names...